# Oracle SQL: How to Query A CSV With No Header/Column Names?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a third party tool which uses CSV Text Drivers which allows for executing SQL queries on CSV data imported into the tool. Most Oracle SQL queries work on this while many don't.

I have a requirement where I have to read and import data into the tool using a CSV file which has no column names or header fields available. How can I execute SQL queries on a table which has no column names or headers defined?

Sample Table:

```
AB  100 GPAA    9876
AC  101 GPAB    9877
AD  102 GPAC    9878
```

Comment: if this tool is executing the queries, then you have to explain what this tool is. we can't help you with sql for a tool using some unknown dialect

Comment: do a `select * where 1=2` and see what column names show up.

Comment: External tables work great on selecting from flat files: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i

Comment: The tool just uses the com.hxtt.sql.text.TextDriver to execute the queries on the CSV files.

Comment: @DanBracuk: I doubt that'd work. how's the app/DB to know the difference between `int=int` and `colnum=int`?

Comment: It knows the difference between 1 and 2.   Since they are never equal, no data will be returned, just the field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, you can specify if your CSV file has a header or not when using the CSV SQL Text driver for interaction with CSV files.

```
jdbc:csv:////<path_to_file>/?_CSV_Header=false;
```

Then, we can have a query like

```
select distinct (column1) as accountID, (column2) as groupID from csv_file_name
```

The parameters `(column1), (column2)...` represent the actual columns in the file from left to right and they have to be written like this for the query to work.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to add the headers before running the queries. Is there a table in which the data will eventually end up? If so, you could export the column names from there first, then append the CSV info to the newly created file afterward.

Comment: I wish that were possible in the tool I am using. I guess there is no other way to just 'demand' to have the headers added into the file.